# Size of constraints in the Z3 Solver()

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

Is there a way for us to get how many constraints were added into the solver? For example, we initialize a z3 solver `s = Solver()` and then adding constraints to it using `s.add()`. How can we get the number of constraints which were finally added to the solver?

Comment: It's customary to either "accept" answers or indicate why they don't work for you with a comment so other users have some feedback on whether the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `assertions` method:

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

i = Int('i')
s.add (i > 1)
s.add (i < 12)

print s.assertions()
print len(s.assertions())
```

This prints:

```
[i > 1, i < 12]
2
```